# Jboss Drools entry points

Tags: jboss, drools

I have a requirement where I need to read the entry-point from property file.
Sample code:

```
Propertyfile:
ep.event=StEntry

String entryPoint = Read from property file(ep.event)
WorkingMemoryEntryPoint entryPoint = ksession.getWorkingMemoryEntryPoint(entryPoint);
```

How can I use entryPoint variable in rule:

```
rule "Test entry point1"
    when
        from entry-point $entryPoint
    then
        System.out.println("Entry type 1");
end
```

If I try the above approach, it is throwing NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't use variables for entry point names. According to [Drools documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e12560), entry points are identified at compile time:

> Entry points are declared implicitly in Drools by directly making use
>   of them in rules. I.e. referencing an entry point in a rule will make
>   the engine, at compile time, to identify and create the proper
>   internal structures to support that entry point.

Could you clarify your use case a little bit more? Why do you need dynamic entry points names? Maybe there are some other ways to achieve what you are looking for.

http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#d0e12560

Comment: Hello Esteban, Thanks for the response. The use case, we have is, we will be getting set of events from network.Each set of events should run on a different DROOLS entry points. Entry points will be configured in property file(user can add/modify entry points). So idea is not to hard code the entry-points, read them from property, and use them in rule. Please help.     rule "Test entry point1"
 when
  from entry-point $epVar//this is the varaiblewhich will hold entry-point name
 then
  System.out.println("entry point 1 "+$ep);
end

Comment: Do you have rules involving Events from multiple entry-points? If not, you can have a multiple KieSessions in a Map and route the Events to the corresponding session.